# Namespace xVal.ServerSide not recognized

Tags: namespaces, xval

I keep getting the error "The type or namespace name 'xVal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" when I include the namespace:

using xVal.ServerSide;

Am I missing something? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple though. Just have to include a dll on the bin folder of the app.